# How can i access and change value of string variable which is declared in another class in FLUTTER/DART

Tags: flutter, dart

basically i want to store name as sting in a seperate class and want to access that Sting name from any class of my project , Also i want to read and update the Sting name from any other class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way it's done in Flutter. You should have 'state' which is accessible in some way from all the widgets that are interested in reading and/or setting its value. When the value is set, it should produce a 'change' event that other widgets can react to. Read about state management and its various incarnations, like 'lifting state up', `InheritedWidget`, `ValueListenable` and the `provider` package.